# How to make all swipable container with the same height in codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to display rows with the same height filed with container and the container contains texts/images. I am trying to display table list for this.

see the image below.

[image]
I would like to display rows with the same height.

Below is the code which i have been used. I have used Swipable container as table row.

```
tableContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
tableContainer.setUIID("transparent");

//Table Header - Start
Container tableHeaderRowContainer = new Container();
tableHeaderRowContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
tableHeaderRowContainer.setScrollable(false);
tableHeaderRowContainer.setUIID("TableHeaderBg");

Container tableHeaderContainer = new Container(new TableLayout(1,columnNames.length));
tableHeaderContainer.setScrollable(false);
tableHeaderContainer.setUIID("TableHeaderBg");

for(int col=0;col<columnNames.length;col++){
  final String colName = columnNames[col];
  Container headerContainer = new Container();
  headerContainer.setUIID("TableHeaderBg");
  Button headerButton = new Button();

  SpanLabel headerTitle = new SpanLabel(colName);
  headerTitle.setTextUIID("TableHeader");
  headerTitle.setUIID("TableHeader");
  headerContainer.addComponent(headerTitle);
  headerContainer.setFocusable(false);
  headerContainer.setLeadComponent(headerButton);
  headerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
 });
 // tableHeaderContainer.add(l1);
 TableLayout.Constraint constraint = ((TableLayout)tableHeaderContainer.getLayout()).createConstraint();
 constraint = ComponentUtils.setTableConstraint(constraint, col); 
 tableHeaderContainer.addComponent(constraint,headerContainer);

} 

selectAllCheckBox = new CheckBox();
selectAllCheckBox.setUIID("TableHeaderCheck");
tableHeaderRowContainer.addComponent(selectAllCheckBox);
tableHeaderRowContainer.addComponent(tableHeaderContainer);
tableContainer.addComponent(tableHeaderRowContainer);
//Table Header - End

//Table list - start
Container tableContainerMain = new Container();
tableContainerMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
tableContainerMain.setScrollableY(true);

for(int row=0;row<data.length;row++){
   String jobReference = jobRefList[row];

   Container tableRowContainer = new Container();
   tableRowContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
   tableRowContainer.setScrollable(false);

   Button actionButton = new Button();
   final Container rowContainer = new Container(new TableLayout(1,columnNames.length));

   if(row%2==0){
       rowContainer.setUIID("even");
       tableRowContainer.setUIID("evenPadding");
   }
   else{
       rowContainer.setUIID("odd");
       tableRowContainer.setUIID("oddPadding");
   }

   rowContainer.setFocusable(false);
   rowContainer.setLeadComponent(actionButton);

   JobDataDetail jobRef = editJobs[row];
   final JobData jobDataRef = Utility.getJobDataWithStatus(jobData);
   jobDataRef.setJobDataDetail(jobRef);

   for(int col=0;col<columnNames.length;col++){
         Label statusLabel = new Label();
         String imageName = "";
         if(data[row][col]!=null && (data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_ACTIVE) 
                 || data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_REACTIVE))){ 
             imageName = "st-completed.png";
         }
         else if(data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_ACTIVE_NONCOMPLETE)){ 
             imageName = "st-incomplete.png";
         }
         else if(data[row][col]!=null && data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_PENDING) ){
             imageName = "st-pending.png";
         }
         else if(data[row][col]!=null && data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_SYNCED) ){
             imageName = "st-synched.png";
         }
         else if(data[row][col]!=null && data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_CHECKIN) ){
             imageName = "st-checkedin.png";
         }
         else if(data[row][col]!=null && data[row][col].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_CLOSED) ){
             imageName = "st-closed.png";
         }

         if(!Utility.isBlankOrNull(imageName)){
              statusLabel = new Label(res.getImage(imageName));
              if(row%2==0){
                  statusLabel.setUIID("evenImageLabel");
           }
           else{
               statusLabel.setUIID("oddImageLabel");
           }
              statusLabel.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
              Container labelContainer = new Container();
           if(row%2==0){
               labelContainer.setUIID("even");
           }
           else{
               labelContainer.setUIID("odd");
           }
           labelContainer.addComponent(FlowLayout.encloseIn(statusLabel));
               TableLayout.Constraint constraint1 = ((TableLayout) rowContainer.getLayout()).createConstraint();
               constraint1 = ComponentUtils.setTableConstraint(constraint1, col);
               rowContainer.addComponent(constraint1, labelContainer);

          }
          else{
             /*
              SpanLabel txtLabel = new SpanLabel((String) data[row][col]);
              txtLabel.setTextUIID("login_title");
              txtLabel.setUIID("transparent");*/

              TextArea txtLabel = new TextArea((String) data[row][col]);
              txtLabel.setUIID("login_title");
              txtLabel.setEditable(false);
              txtLabel.setRows(2);
              txtLabel.setScrollVisible(false);


              TableLayout.Constraint constraint1 = ((TableLayout) rowContainer.getLayout()).createConstraint();
              constraint1 = ComponentUtils.setTableConstraint(constraint1, col);
              rowContainer.addComponent(constraint1, txtLabel);

          }

   SwipeableContainer swipeableContainer = new SwipeableContainer(null,actionButtons[row], rowContainer);
   swipeableContainer.setUIID("transparent");
   swipeableContainer.setSmoothScrolling(true);
   swipeableContainer.setSwipeActivated(true);
   Container checkContainer = new Container();
   if(row%2==0){
       checkContainer.setUIID("even");
   }
   else{
       checkContainer.setUIID("odd");
   }
   CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
   c.setName(jobReference);
       if(row%2==0){
       c.setUIID("evenCheck");
   }
   else{
       c.setUIID("oddCheck");
   }
   c.setVerticalAlignment(TOP);
   checkBoxArr.add(c);
   checkContainer.addComponent(FlowLayout.encloseIn(c));
   tableRowContainer.addComponent(checkContainer);
   tableRowContainer.addComponent(swipeableContainer);
   tableContainerMain.addComponent(tableRowContainer);
}
}

tableContainer.addComponent(tableContainerMain);
//Table list - End

addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tableContainer);
```

Edited:

I have applied solution given by diamond, but still it seems not solved as it has to be.

see in the image, the third line seen upto the given height.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextArea was designed to grow by the size of its content, you can add limit to that:

```
TextArea txtLabel = new TextArea((String) data[row][col]);
txtLabel.setUIID("login_title");
txtLabel.setEditable(false);
txtLabel.setRows(2);
txtLabel.setGrowLimit(2);
txtLabel.setScrollVisible(false);
```

Comment: @Diamond- thanks for your efforts. I have applied same solution given by you but still I am  facing issue with the rows.see Edited comment in my post.

Comment: That's a bug,  please open an issue for that on GitHub and it would be resolved...

Comment: That's not a bug but the documentation should probably be clearer here. Grow limit only applies to preferred size, so the text area won't request more height than 2 rows (hence won't "grow" beyond). But it can still have more rows, we can't control that. So it did limit the height to two rows but it seems other elements in the row push it to be "slightly larger than the exact height of two rows hence the "peek". Try setting 3 as the number of rows and the cut should be more accurate. Alternatively add a bit of padding/margin below/above the text area to give it less space.

Comment: @Shai-thanks shai for suggestions. It seems fine when adding margin to textArea.